# Can you answer these two difficult vector questions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

[image]

**Figure 1**

[image]

1) Determine the value of **FB**.

2) Determine the magnitude of **FA + FB**.

(I know that the answer must be in Newtons. But other than that, I've very lost on what to do next. Please help!)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The horizontal components of Fa and Fb must cancel - from this you can find their relative magnitude. You use that to find the relative magnitude of their vertical component (one equation); you already know their sum is 4000 N (second equation). Two equations, two unknowns.

Comment: I already tried that and got Fb = 3208.37335 N, which the homework website told me is wrong.

Comment: Can you work out the problem to see if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I get Fb = 4000/(cos(48)*sin(32)/sin(48)+cos(32))